# how to restrict access to serverless api via resource policy?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-policies

a serverless api gateway stack built via cloudformation template ( see below) . I added a resource policy to whitelist a particular IP address. Does this block all other IP address, without specifying a black list or do I have add a IpRangeBlacklist values as well?

```
Resources:
  serverlessapiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Auth:
        ResourcePolicy:
          IpRangeWhitelist:
            - "10.20.30.40"
```

Comment: Test it and let us know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verified, only list of IP under *IpRangeWhitelist* range are allowed. I wonder if there is a way to customize the error message we get, when not allowed.